# long long epoch time to tm

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, windows64

I have a value for milliseconds since epoch stored in a long long variable milliseconds_since_epoch. I wish to convert this to some more standard and easier to process time structure like perhaps tm. Is there some library function to do this?

I have a 64bit PC and am compiling to produce 64 bit code.

**EDIT:** just to be clear, my milliseconds_since_epoch is not a measure of the time now. In fact I have a collection of different milliseconds_since_epoch's each referring to a different historical time.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch

Comment: Or even  time_point_cast std::chrono::time_point_cast

Comment: If the epoch is 1970-01-01, just divide by 1000 and pass to `ctime` or `localtime`/`gmtime` (and then maybe `strftime`).